# FInd inside two different nested objects the equal properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, find

I got some api Im working with related to two nested objects inside it, trying to find the item in one these objects that coincide with the value of what ever the item the other object has.

For that i got these two objects:

```
myObj={
...
   answers:[
           {"id": 'zoo',"foo":"1"},
           {"id": "bear","foo":"2"},
           {"id": "mangoes","foo":"3"}
   ],
   bar:[
           {"key": 'jungle'},
           {"key": "zoo"},
           {"key": "beach"}

   ]
}
```

thus the idea here is find in ***answer*** item the id coinciding with the key value in item ***bar***... then return the answer selected by that criteria.
In this specific case would be the one related to ***zoo***

My implementation was using of find() two times, but didn´t get any result about it

```
         myObj.answers.find((specificAnswer) =>
            (myObj.bar).find((value) => {
              specificAnswer.id === value.key;
            })
          ).foo
```

Would be nice to get some help about how to improve this implementation.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
obj.answers.filter(answer => obj.bar.find(bar => bar.key === answer.id))
```